# When a google action is launched implicitly can we skip the part where it prompts the user to confirm?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am trying to use google assistant sdk on raspberry pi.
I created my custom actions project in google actions console.
I am able to interact from my device using run_assistant_audio by using a phrase like "Talk to my raspberry pi"

I have 2 questions for which I could not find any answers in the documentation.
1) Once I launch my agent via explicit invocation then queries like "What is the weather in Agra" are not working. If I don't launch my agent and just run this query it gives the weather information."  Is there a way to keep my agent active all the time and redirect to google assistant for queries which my agent does not handle ?

2) If I try to implicitly launch application google assistant asks for confirmation whether I want to launch my agent. Can this confirmation part be skipped ?

Answer (score 0):

1. In your current workflow, you cannot use Assistant as a fallback. The model of development is Actions being part of Assistant, not the other way around.

You could use the Assistant SDK on your fulfillment, getting run for fallback, but not using the Assistant on the device.

Additionally, an action is not expected to always be active. As such, your expected behavior is not something that is intended.

2. If you're doing implicit triggering, then your query is somewhat ambiguous. While Assistant may have a good guess as to start the action, it's possible you didn't want that. The disambiguation prompt is intentional to ensure that it doesn't open up an action you didn't want.